# Response.Redirect asp didn't work after $post jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, facebook

I do something to pass Facebook ressponse by post the value to currentpage

```
 function testAPI() {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {

                $.post('http://localhost:50790/TestPage.aspx',
                { fbid: response.id, firstname: response.first_name, lastname: response.last_name, email: response.email, bday: response.birthday },
                function (result) {

                });
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + response.id + response.email + response.gender + response.birthday + '.');

            });
        }
```

and I do some checkin on my code behind :

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fbid = Request.Form["fbid"];
            var fname = Request.Form["firstname"];
            var lname = Request.Form["lastname"];
            var email = Request.Form["email"];
            var bday = Request.Form["bday"];
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (fbid != null)
                {

                    CheckFBLogin(fbid.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
```

my testing is on `CheckFBLogin` if the result okay, It'll make the user login to website, else it should redirect to others page / registration page.

```
 public void CheckFBLogin(string Fbid)
        {


            CustomerSelfCareSoapClient service = new CustomerSelfCareSoapClient();
            service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _Username;
            service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _Password;
            GResult result = service.CheckFBLogin(Fbid.ToString(), "");
            if (result != null)
            {
                if (result.Code == 100)
                {
                    //login
                }
                else
                {

                    Response.Redirect("~/callback.aspx", true);

                }
            }
        }
```

I dont know what happen, I usually do something like this to check login but pure asp and c#. any I idea why the page wont redirect ?

Comment: have you tried debugging your code to see in what if statement the code falls / if the IF statement actually calls to Response.Redirect?

Comment: Also try adding some exception handling - response.redirect will often fail because some data has already been flushed to the client.

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv yes when I debug the code it pass to the response redirect code

Comment: @steve haven't tried that one I'm afraid that one the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to duplicate this behavior with Mono.  On my system, the problem is that the jquery $post() method actually enables the Page.IsPostBack property in code behind so that all logic in the `if (!Page.IsPostBack) {}` condition fails to run.

My advice would be use ASP.NET's [WebMethod] attribute alongside jquery.  [Dave Ward has documented this well](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/).  If you're doing a lot of asynchronous client side JSON calls, you might consider ASP.NET's MVC implementation if the scope of your project allows it.

Comment: Yep just curious about `Page.IsPostBack` .  I wish I could recreate the project to MVC, but it takes time, so I think I'll use `[WebMethod]` to my asp